# Cloud Firestore get count of document in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic3, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

As Cloud Firestore is in beta version. There is less info available on Google.
I just want to know how can we get total no of document present in a specific collection. We can do this by a foreach loop but this is not a good way as I think. I tried `length` function but it is not working.

```
import {AngularFirestore} from 'angularfire2/firestore';

........

constructor(private afs:AngularFirestore) {

     console.log(this.afs.collection(`/cart`).length);  //undefined 

     let ref = this.afs.collection('/cart').valueChanges();
     ref.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element.length);  // total 4 (works fine)
     });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as shown below.

Using **Javascript API**

```
db.collection(`/cart`).get().then((querySnapshot)=> {      
    console.log(querySnapshot.size); 
});
```

**Angularfire2:**

```
 let count = this.afs.collection(`/cart`).snapshotChanges().map(c => {
      return c.length;
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response. Now when I run above code it give me error `this.afs.collection(...).get is not a function`. I am using `angularfire2` for my project.

Comment: this is not working as well. It looks like that function is not going inside `.map();`. count is returning an objcet. code is not reaching at `c.length`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

IMPORT

```
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
```

CLASS

```
 cartCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>; //Firestore collection

constructor(private afs:AngularFirestore) {
  this.cartCollection = this.afs.collection('cart');
  this.cartCollection.snapshotChanges().map(data => {
    console.log(data.length);
  });
}
```

Comment: same as above. It is not going inside `console.log`.

Answer (score 0):

**Angularfire2**

```
let count = this.afs
    .collection(`/cart`)
    .snapshotChanges()
    .subscribe(c => {
        return c.length;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is now a **getCountFromServer()** method from Firestore.

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#cloud-firestore_2